# What happens when we build a Docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, dockerhub

Suppose I have the .NET Framework 4.8 SDK and runtime installed on my local machine. I have a dockerfile having the base image instruction
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8`. When I build the image, would it install the .NET Framework 4.8 SDK and runtime as layers or create layer from the already installed .NET Framework 4.8 SDK and runtime present on my machine?

Comment: Why not try it out and se what happens? Usually, building a image does not install any software

Comment: Of course it does! There is always a base layer on top of which we add other data (which form layers or instructions) in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Yes, but that base layer is not "installed" as any other software

Comment: Yes that's true. However by "installation" I meant installing the stuffs necessary that make up what we call the "layer". That's the thing, its different from the traditional installation but the essence of having the necessary SDK and runtime is there in the form of layers in the container world.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define  `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8` It will Only Contain the SDK and .Net Frameworks of version 4.8.

It won't reuse or create a layer from the .NET Framework SDK and runtime installed on your local machine. The reason is docker containers and Images are wholly isolated from your local Machine.

If you are willing to Copy your Current Runtimes and Code into a docker container then you can use `COPY` in `Dockerfile`.